# Customizing ASP.NET Identity

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 and I've customised my ASP.NET Identity user as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I can't see where I would configure Identity Server 4 to include these 2 properties in the claims collection.  I've had a look through some of the Identity Server 4 samples but can't see any examples.

I'd ideally like to map these 2 user properties to the `given_name` and `family_name` claims.

I'm currently hooking up to the notifications and querying the `userinfo` endpoint (hybrid flow?).  So I'm not sure if this is configuration of Identity Server or customization of the `userinfo` endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering why there is no documentation on this.  It lead me to realise that I'm probably doing it wrong.

I'd not seen the table `AspNetUserClaims` created as part of ASP.NET Identity.  I added my claim data into here and the claim data pulls through as part of the `profile`.

In the `POST` method for `AccountController.Register` I added:

```
var givenNameClaim = new IdentityUserClaim<string>()
{
    ClaimType = "given_name",
    ClaimValue = model.FirstName
};

var familyNameClaim = new IdentityUserClaim<string>()
{
    ClaimType = "family_name",
    ClaimValue = model.LastName
};

var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
user.Claims.Add(givenNameClaim);
user.Claims.Add(familyNameClaim);
```

Comment: If you are using aspnet identity to manage user then this would be the correct answer. since you already have a IProfileService implementation that will use these values. I had to make a slight change when creating claims since I am using 2.1.                                             
 `await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user,
                        new List<Claim>
                        {
                            new Claim("given_name", model.FirstName),
                            new Claim("family_name", model.LastName)
                        });`

Comment: This may help some folks if doing SPA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201244/identify-roles-with-spa-and-net-core-3

Answer (score 9):

In order to include your custom claims, you need to implement your own `GetProfileDataAsync()` method using the `IProfileService`. This method is being called everytime a user claim is requested.

Here is my implementation of IProfileService.

```
public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public CustomProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);

        if (user == null) return;

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("username", user.UserName),
            new Claim("email", user.Email),
            new Claim("firstname", user.FirstName),
            new Claim("lastname", user.LastName)
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("role", role));
        }

        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        foreach (var userClaim in userClaims)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(userClaim.Type, userClaim.Value));
        }

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(context.Subject.GetSubjectId());
        context.IsActive = user.IsActive;
    }
}
```

Then you will have to add this following line to `Startup.ConfigureServices()`

`services.AddScoped<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();`

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution but I cannot see that my custom profile service is ever called. Breakpoints added on ctor and all methods - nothing (and yes - it is wired in properly in DI)

Comment: Instead of simply adding it as a scoped service, you need to add it to IdentityServer by using the `AddProfileService` extension method on the `IIdentityServerBuilder`.
E.g. `services.AddIdentityServerDefaults<ApplicationUser>().AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done: In AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback I added this:

```
//Add claim even if client didn't ask for it
additionalClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "email@email.com"));
```

then I added the claim to the `access_token` by dependency injecting my `ProfileService` class and adding the claims in the `MyProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync` like this:

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    Claim emailClaim = context.Subject.Claims.Where<Claim>(claim => claim.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Email)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (emailClaim != null)
    {
        claims.Add(emailClaim);
    }

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where does `additionalClaims` come from, it's not declared in my method or controller?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips It's just a `new List<Claim>()` I created. Look at the samplse where `await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username,  provider, props, additionalClaims.ToArray());` is called