# ASP NET Identity Role Base Authorisation - Authorise by role returns Forbidden in react fetch

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-identity, user-roles

being new to ASP NET I am using a React JS default app with ASP .NET in Visual Studio 2022.

I have setup the Identity with SQL Server and login etc works fine. I want to setup Role based Authorization.

I have a new controller that looks like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public UsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) 
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    //public UsersController() { }


    // GET: api/<UsersController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>> Get()
    {
        // ApplicationUser u = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

The issue is that whenever I change [Authorize] without a role the react fetch works fine, but with the role it returns FORBIDDEN 403 error.

I have tried both claims as well as roles to be added

```
                await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "#ond@BKD678!");

                var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SuperAdmin");

                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, UserRoles.SuperAdmin.ToString());
                await userManager.AddClaimAsync(defaultUser, claim);
```

I have used the standard code that gets created when you create a new project

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores();

```
        builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
        

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
            })
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

for reference my react fetch looks like the below

```
async populateUsersData() 
{
        const token = await authService.getAccessToken();
        const response = await fetch('users', {
            headers: !token ? {} : { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ userslist: data, loading: false });
}
```

Login, authentication etc works fine... but the fetch call always returns forbidden whenever try [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")] but works fine with I use [Authorize]. I want to use role based authentication...

Please help!! I have tried many things... what am I missing???

PS: the code shown is trying to just list the full set of registered users for a SuperAdmin user.

Comment: When you add a role to [Authorize] can you access the controller directly (not using react)?

Comment: How do you mean - access the controller directly?

Comment: By using a browser to call the URL users/get

Comment: i do not know but by e.g using below URL https://localhost:44408/users returns nothing.. shows a blank page... but fetch works fine....

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is the response from Sike Mullivan in the below link

[Identify roles with SPA and .NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201244/identify-roles-with-spa-and-net-core-3)